# Is it possible to pass regex strings as args to a Python CLI tool using argparse?

Tags: python, regex, linux, bash, python-2.7

I'm writing a script to search a logfile for a given python regex pattern. Setting aside the fact that this would be *much* easier to do using a simple Bash script, can it be done in Python? Here's what I've run into:

#### Assumptions:

- I'm trying to analyze the file `/var/log/auth.log`

  - (for the sake of simplicity, I'm omitting the ability to choose a file.)
- the name of my cli module is `logscour`.
- for the sake of argument, `logscour` takes only one arg called `regex_in`.

#### Intended usage:

```
[root@localhost]: # logscour '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
```

Should return the lines inside of `/var/log/auth.log` that contain an IPv4 address.

I want to find a sort of anti-`re.escape()`, as I am in backslash-hell. Here's a snippet:

```
import re
import argparse

def main(regex_in, logfile='/var/log/auth.log'):
    ## Herein lies the problem!
    # user_regex_string = re.escape(regex_in) #<---DOESN'T WORK, EVEN MORE ESCAPE-SLASHES
    # user_regex_string = r'{}'.format(regex_in) #<---DOESN'T WORK
    user_regex_string = regex_in                 #<---DOESN'T WORK EITHER GAHHH
    
    with open(logfile, 'rb+') as authlog:
        for aline in authlog:
            if re.match(user_regex_string, aline):
                print aline

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("regex_in", nargs="?", help="enter a python-compliant regex string. Parentheses & matching groups not supported.", default=None)
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if not args.regex_in:
        raise argparse.ArgumentError('regex_in', message="you must supply a regex string")
    main(args.regex_in)
```

This is giving me back nothing, as one would expect due to the fact that I'm using Python2.7 and these are bytestrings I'm dealing with.

Does anyone know a way to convert `'foo'` to `r'foo'`, or an "opposite" for `re.escape()`?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything; the shell string is properly quoted and there are no Python string literals involved. Does each line of your log file *start* with an IP address? `re.match` implicitly anchors the regex to the start of the line. You might want `re.search` instead.

Comment: Also, why are you opening a text file in binary mode?

Comment: `'foo'` and `r'foo'` are the same thing.  The purpose of the `r''` prefix isn't to turn a string into a regex; it's to keep the Python interpreter from treating escape sequences like `\n` inside the string specially and instead pass them through **r**aw.

Comment: @chepner, this a OS-dependent module for a larger, OS-**independent** log-auditing package I'm building. I open everything in binary-plus mode for consistency & to fit my assertion-modules & loggers...which I guess you could call _meta_-loggers lol. Consequently, I also don't want to rely on a particular shell-command being present, so no `sh` or `subprocess` allowed. : [

Comment: Also, my shell was including the `'`'s from my input arg. I removed those & @Eric Dunhill's advice worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user_regex_string = re.compile(regex_in)
```

and

```
re.search(user_regex_string, aline)
```

should work fine. You need [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead of [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) because the IP address isn't necessarily at the start of a line.

I always find `re.match` very convenient in order to introduce subtle bugs in my code. :)

On my server, `logscour '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'` outputs:

```
May 28 17:38:53 dmzXX sshd[1736]: Received disconnect from 123.200.20.158: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
May 28 17:38:54 dmzXX sshd[1738]: Invalid user guest from 123.200.20.158
...
```

That being said `grep -P 'pattern' file` would also work:

```
grep -P "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" /var/log/auth.log
```

`-P` stands for:

> ```
>    -P, --perl-regexp
>           Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below).  This is highly experimental and  grep  -P  may  warn  of unimplemented features.
> ```

`-P` is needed in order to interpret `\d` as `[0-9]`

Comment: Thanks for this! For the first time in my life, `re.compile()` is actually useful. Also, (after I stripped out the single-quotes that came with the regex, your note about `re.search()` vs `re.match()` fixed my problem.